# Scripting a permanent CTRL / CAPS swap in Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I have a bash script that I use to configure a vanilla Ubuntu (10.10 Maverick Meerkat) installation to be exactly the way I want it. I make extensive use of gconftool-2 to configure the desktop, set up shortcut keys, etc.

Now, I'm trying to swap the CTRL and CAPS keys. I have found two ways of doing this:

- In Gnome, go to System -> Preferences
  -> Keyboard -> Layout -> Options and make the change in there. This works
  well, but I don't know how to script
  this; the setting doesn't seem to be
  stored in the usual place as I can't
  find it with gconf-editor.
- Add the
  line `setxkbmap -option "ctrl:swapcaps"` to my `.bashrc` file.
  That works too, until I suspend the
  machine & then resume it. At that
  point the CTRL and CAPS behaviour
  return to normal, until I cause
  .bashrc to be run again by opening a
  new shell. This behaviour has been
  reported as a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=639145) in RedHat.

Could someone please suggest a way of switching those keys that is both permanent, and can be scripted? I'm sure I must be missing something obvious here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an even quicker Gnome-only solution.  Thanks to [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10521252&postcount=3) from [gmargo](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=1009937) over on Ubuntu Forums:

> If you're running Gnome, then all you need to do is create a file $HOME/.Xkbmap with this content:
>
> `-option ctrl:swapcaps`
>
> Log out then back in.
>
> Update: I just confirmed that the setting lasts across a suspend/resume.

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished this on my RHEL system in a generic way by adding this to the beginning of `~/.xinitrc:

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc
```

And the contents of `.xmodmaprc`:

```
!! Swap Caps_Lock and Control_L
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
```